# Numerical methods for ODE: Taylor vs. Interpolation approaches

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Hy everybody!

I am new to the subject "numerical methods for ODE". I read some basic literature but since most of the concepts and methods are new to me, I wanted to ask you, if you could give me feedback if I understand everything correctly:

There are two numeric approaches for solving differential equations:

a) Based on Taylor Series Approximation: Euler, Runge Kutta, etc. Goal: to have similar accuracy as with Taylor series but without calculating derivatives. Work-around was developed, where you only evaluate functions at certain points without calculating derivatives.

b) Based on Interpolation Polynomials: Multi-Step Methods, Collocation methods: Make use of past information; no intermediate calculations (as in Runge-Kutta) . General idea: fit a polynomial using this past data + extrapolate from tn to tn+1

Are ther caes, where Runge-Kutta methods are better compared to Multi-step methods and vice versa?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

a) "but without calculating derivatives" This is not correct, unfortunately. You still need to calculate the derivatives at the given point to get the coefficients of $x$ terms. As can be seen in the definition of Taylor series $f(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$

For your last question, I believe [this post](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node40.html) will do.

> The main advantages of Runge-Kutta methods are that they are easy to implement, they are very stable, and they are ``self-starting'' (i.e., unlike muti-step methods, we do not have to treat the first few steps taken by a single-step integration method as special cases). The primary disadvantages of Runge-Kutta methods are that they require significantly more computer time than multi-step methods of comparable accuracy, and they do not easily yield good global estimates of the truncation error.
>
> However, for *the straightforward dynamical systems* under investigation in this course, the advantage of the relative simplicity and ease of use of Runge-Kutta methods far outweighs the disadvantage of their relatively high computational cost.